# AWS Free Tier bandwidth limit

Tags: amazon, amazon-ec2

Is there some kind of monthly bandwidth limit on Amazon's AWS EC2 free tier under which `t2.micro` instances are free for almost an year?

I couldn't find anything in their [faqs](https://aws.amazon.com/free/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no bandwidth limit, unless you are unwilling to pay for what you use.

So, if you're asking whether there is a **free** bandwidth limit, then, yes.

From the page you linked, the 12 month free tier includes this:

> 15 GB of bandwidth out aggregated across all AWS services

This is bandwidth out from AWS toward the Internet, total from all services (EC2, S3, etc.) that you use.  After 15GB each month, the normal transfer rates apply.  Inbound bandwidth is not charged, on most services...only outbound.  Data transferred between AWS services in the same region on the same account are generally not billed.

Comment: AWS specs do not specify it is 15GB per month. For other usage parameters it is specifically written "for per month". But for data-transfer it is not mentioned. So I think it is per year. Otherwise for on-demand usage rate is pretty low, first 1GB free, then $0.09/GB till 10TB . And get reduced by approx $0.005 for next 10 TB usage. Follow link to know more about data transfer rates https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

Comment: @rahul.deshmukhpatil I concede that *"Data Transfer
15 GB of bandwidth out aggregated across all AWS services"* at https://aws.amazon.com/free/ doesn't *specifically* say "per month" even though that seems the obvious context, since everything is billed by the month... but you will also find "**15 GB per month** of bandwidth out, aggregated across all AWS services" mentioned in many places like https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ and 
https://aws.amazon.com/gamelift/pricing/ ... so, yes, it is 15 GB per month for the first 12 months, and the allowance does not roll over from month to month.